# Extent reports - Image not displayed when html page is opened with Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

In Intellij IDEA 2019.3.3, I have a java project with selenium, testng and extent reports which runs automated tests on a website. The code generates html reports for the tests and saves screenshots of test failures to display them in the reports. The code puts the absolute path for screenshots in the html code of the failed tests in these reports.

When I open a html test report via Intellij (report > right click > open in browser > chrome), the thumbnail of the screenshot is not present. There is no placeholder either. Is this bug? If not, then do I need to change any setting in Intellij IDEA for the thumbnail to show up?

PS - I tried to open the report with chrome and firefox and faced the same issue. I have not tested this with a simple java project having an html page in a folder in that project. You can try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is a bug or a feature in Intellij IDEA. But, the simple solution is to open your html report directly with your browser. The image thumbnails show up there.